# StackExchange login account not shows in My Logins screen

Tags: bug, login

I have enable `MyOpenID` login for my account.

[image: My Logins]

Its not showing **StackExchange** login.

When I add my *gmail* login, its shows **StackExchange**.

[image: StackExchange Login]

Comment: Possibly related bug report on MSE: [Option to add a Stack Exchange Login to Existing Account has gone AWOL](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234664/option-to-add-a-stack-exchange-login-to-existing-account-has-gone-awol)

Comment: @psubsee2003: before the OP got the email addresses removed, the Stack Exchange email and the Google email are the same. The OP just added them a few hours ago. The OP claims that for some reason they have a SE login without creating one.